# C# WPF Closing Webbrowser Hosting Excel

Tags: c#, excel, wpf

I am using the Webbrowser to open an Excel file from within a C# WPF application.

When I attempt to close Excel I get the error "Excel ran out of resource while attempting to calculate one or more formulas. As a result, these formulas cannot be evaluated.  I am using the following code to close Excel, any ideas what is going wrong?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
if (excelWebBrowser != null)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = excelWebBrowser.webBrowser.Document as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook;
    webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
    xlWorkBook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
    xlWorkBook = null;

        excelApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
        excelApp = null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```

I also tried a few variants on this using webBrowser.Dispose() but get the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered hosting excel directly? Never done this myself, but I think this sort of approach https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati

Comment: Yes considered other approaches but found WebBrowser to be the most stable

Comment: And the approach you suggested sadly doesn't work with excel, i tried and failed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415239/embedded-excel-changing-window-style-makes-ui-unresponsive

Comment: Turns out this was caused by a xll add-in that misbehaved.